# EventLoopFuture causing `Invalid state: unable to write message`

Tags: swift, swift-nio, grpc-swift

I'm using grpc-swift and the `ClientInterceptor` to add an auth token to requests. I have implemented the delegate method for `send` as follows

```
    override func send(_ part: GRPCClientRequestPart<Request>, promise: EventLoopPromise<()>?, context: ClientInterceptorContext<Request, Response>) {
        
        guard case .metadata(var headers) = part else {
            return context.send(part, promise: promise)
        }
        
        let p = context.eventLoop.makePromise(of: String.self)
        p.completeWithTask {
            "My Token" // In reality this is actually an async function like `await myActor.idToken`
        }
        p.futureResult.whenSuccess { token in
            print(context.eventLoop.inEventLoop) // This returns `true`
            headers.add(name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer \(token)")
            context.send(.metadata(headers), promise: promise)
        }
    }
```

I need to read the values from an `actor` which requires `async/await` to get the values hence the use of creating a promise and then `p.completeWithTask`.

The problem I am facing is when doing this and then calling the `context.send(_,promise:)` is that I receive an error back saying `Invalid state: unable to write message`, looking at the docs it says `/// An invalid state was encountered. This is a serious implementation error.`, I'm clearly doing something very wrong here but for the life of me I am not sure what?

If this is used without promises/futures it all works fine. I'm not sure if I am using the `p.completeWithTask` & `p.futureResult.whenSuccess` correctly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you end up re-ordering messages. Usually, a gRPC request/response will be `.metadata(...)` followed by `.message(...)` and finally `.end`. And the order is important. If you disobey the correct order, you'll get into an illegal state.

So what could happen to you is the following:

1. you receive a `.metadata(...)` which you don't immediately forward because you asynchronously get the auth token
2. you receive the `.message(...)` which you immediately forward
3. (irrelevant because we're already in a bad state) you finish the async auth and forward the augmented `.metadata(...)`

See what's going on now? You might be forwarding `.message` *before* `.metadata` which is illegal and would get you into that state.

So how can you fix this? I think you need to manually buffer all further `part`s you receive until you managed to get the augmented `.metadata(...)` one out. That's not incredibly hard but also kinda annoying.

This issue is very similar to what you're doing btw: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/issues/1181

Particularly this snippet from @glbrntt's response

> You'll also have to make sure that within your interceptor you appropriately buffer any request parts to ensure that request parts are sent in the correct oder (i.e. you could receive a request message to send before the asynchronous code to fetch a token has completed).

---

I filed a number of bugs on gRPC Swift about this:

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/issues/1618
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/issues/1619
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/issues/1620

Comment: Oh wow, yeah that looks like it what may be the issue :-(. What's the safety way to buffer these parts? I imagine some sort of dictionary with the parts in the correct order, but what should the key be?

Comment: Just stick them in an array on your interceptor. And once you're done with the auth, you forward them in order. Here's a completely unrelated example (not grpc) that does a similar thing: https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/pull/2402/files